# Documentation for Usage of the API Key in AtTask

Tags: attask

The countdown dashboard released by AtTask makes use of the API key. There is no documentation on how to use this, what level of security it provides or if there are any other features associated with it. It appears that usage is as simple as adding &apiKey=thekeyhere to the URL.

Does anyone have any more detailed documentation on this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I have since figured this out. For anyone with a similar question, all you need to do is add apiKey= to the URL. For example

https://idt.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/task?apiKey={your API key here}

That's it. Please keep in mind that an API key is linked to an admin account and will have the effect of giving admin access to any user working in the tool you have created. Obviously this only applies to functionality that you expose to the user.